# Comparing Integer Array in Linq Query

Tags: asp.net, arrays, linq

One of the requirements of a module I am currently building requires me to select data using Linq but the ids are being passed to me thru an integer array

```
        var CheckedArray = Request["doc_download"];
        string[] detailIds = CheckedArray.Split(',');
        List<int> dtIds = new List<int>();
        foreach (string words in detailIds)
        {
            dtIds.Add(Int32.Parse(words));
        }


      using (var ctx = new Connect2020Entities())
        {
           DetailList = (from userDetail in ctx.DocumentDetail
           where userDetail.ID == <!-- items in dtIds --> //<<I do not know what could be used to compare all of the data from the array in a single query>>

           select new DetailList()
           {
             FilePath = userDetail.FilePath
           }).ToList<UserDocument>();
        }
```

What could be done so that all of the ids inside the integer array can be compared inside the query in one go. I currently could not think of a viable logic that will allow the values in the array to be used as parameters in the query I am using.

*The DocumentDetail field ID is an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try is use `Contains()`

```
ctx.DocumentDetail.Where(ele => dtIds.Contains(ele.ID)).ToList();
```

or in your current syntax

```
where dtIds.Contains(userDetail.ID)
```